# How to create an ISO from a scratched DVD

Tags: 11.10

I'm trying to create a back up for a DVD of mine which is scratched a bit. K3b and Brasero have so far failed as the process gets stuck around 93 percent. Any help to make this process successful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best bet is to try improving the disc surface by polishing with toothpaste ([yes, seriously](http://lifehacker.com/155741/macgyver-tip-fix-scratched-cds-with-toothpaste)) or [furniture polish](http://howto.wired.com/wiki/Fix_a_Scratched_DVD).

For software, you can try [Ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html) but you will have the best odds trying to repair the disc surface first.

Depending on what country you are in, you may be able to obtain a backup of your DVD from an online source via [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/). Ask a lawyer if you're not sure.